# Create a new database without using MySQL Workbench

Tags: mysql, database, mysql-workbench

There is MySQL installed on machine but MySQL Workbench is not installed. Generally, we do create the DB using the workbench. 
**Is there any way to create a new Database without using MySQL Workbench?**

Comment: Strange question, there are loads of alternatives to workbench but you should always instal client so that you can manage the dB. The question suggests you want to instal dB but not an ide?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It can be easily done by using the below command. You can do this via CLI via [execute](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/mysql-command-options.html#option_mysql_execute) option:

```
mysql -u username -p -e "CREATE DATABASE `new_database_name_to_create`";
```